# Exit Strategy: How to communicate / configure my fiat bank when selling large amounts of crypto in a short period of time

Tags: banks, financial-regulations

Anyone can readily see by my previous questions that I have virtually no idea what I'm doing. Be that as it may, it seems very realistic that I may become a bitcoin (multi?)millionaire within the next 12-36 months. I am rapidly headed in that direction with no further action necessary on my part.

If I get to that point, I'm not going to wait around to see if I can become a billionaire. I'm going to get out at a level I can buy a house and retire.

However, I am not prepared for all this. I know even less about being rich than I do about bitcoin. And one of my questions is becoming

1. How is my bank going to react to massive amounts of deposits in a short period of time? (For example, $100,000+ a month as I liquidate my crypto)
2. What can I do to keep my bank from some type of adverse reaction: freezing my account or launching an investigation or worse?

I will have records from the exchanges (including local bitcoins) of every sale documenting it's a crypto-currency sale as opposed to some kind of proceeds from criminal activity. And I will set aside the 15% for capital gains needed to give the IRS.

I don't consider myself a paranoid person; however, the owner of my bank is the man who called bitcoin a fraud.

**Update**

Lo and behold, what I fear is not imaginary. It actually happened to at least one guy. See this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/224mu4/chase_closed_my_personal_account_and_is_holding/) article. Like him, almost all my transactions are to / from Chase and Coinbase. And here's another guy, same thing:

[image]

**Update 2**

I called Chase and I was very blunt about my intentions. I realize their Customer Support Department is probably the least in the know with regards to what the Fraud Prevention Department would or wouldn't do in a given situation. But they told me, if I started making large deposits frequently, they would pull me aside and, and offer me an upgraded set of accounts. He told me it's no different than being successful with an E*Trade account. I am also gradually working to get my Coinbase limits increased by progressively making larger and larger transactions on their site. So, when I'm ready to sell I can sell and withdraw more in a given period of time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should consult a financial advisor at your local jurisdiction

Comment: The one thing *not* to do is to try to adjust the amounts or timing of your transactions to minimize scrutiny or reporting.  That is a crime in itself ("structuring", [31 USC 5324 (a) (3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/31/5324)), even if the transactions themselves are perfectly legitimate.

Comment: To cover your bases, you might like to get an account with a different bank just in case your current one gives you trouble?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular, I appreciate your suggestion, but my goal is to prevent the trouble from occurring in the first place, not run away from it, so I would like to know what all I can do with my bank in advance or during the sales to prevent issues.

Comment: This question may be better asked on the Money StackExchange site (https://money.stackexchange.com) where they have a bitcoin tag.